# When using my PS3 controller as a gamepad, how can I turn it off properly?

Tags: controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I've been using my PS3 controller as a gamepad quite a bit recently. I'm using [MotioninJoy's DS3 tool](http://www.motioninjoy.com/download), with the controller connected with a USB cable to the desktop. Everything is working great, except that each time I close my computer or disconnect the controller it "panics" and turns on my PS3, at which point I have to go and close it.

Is there any way to properly close the controller before closing my computer so that it doesn't do that, or perhaps make it forget about the PS3 so that it doesn't turn it on once it starts panicking?

Comment: +1 been having the same issue.  Curious to see if there's a solution.

Comment: Have you tried holding the PS3 controller PS button down for 10 secs?

Comment: @Adanion I did indeed, but that didn't achieve anything in particular.

Comment: @Aubergine The video tutorial on the [MotionJoy forums](http://forums.motioninjoy.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1186) showed that holding the PS button down for 10 seconds turned off the controller. This most likely will only work if you are connected through bluetooth and not wired. (Go to 4m20s on the youtube video to see the 10 second disconnect).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to find something that works for me, and it appears that the answer was right under my nose. The DS3 tool's main window has a "disconnect" button, as can be seen here on the lower left:

[image: MotionInJoy]

As long as I make sure to press it before shutting down my computer, the controller stays dormant and doesn't bother my PS3.

Answer (score 7):

If you reset the PS3 controller then it should no longer be synced with your PS3, and won't cause your PS3 to turn on.

[image: reset button]

You can use a paperclip or similar object to **gently** press the reset button.

Comment: Sounds great! I'll give it a try as soon as I get back home.

Comment: Out of the frying pan and into the fire... Sorry, I would rather turn off my PS3 every time I disconnect the controller from the PC, than have to resync the controller every time I want to play PS3.  Anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I can see why you wouldn't consider this the best solution, but seeing how I have 3 controllers, I can definitely "sacrifice" one of them.

Comment: Tried this one, but it didn't work for some reason. I even tried pressing and holding, but my controller refuses to forget about the PS3.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've tried everything and I cannot make the controller forget the PS3. It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the PS button till the lights go off, instead of disconnecting

Answer (score 1):

PS button + Start  button together

Answer (score 0):

Holding the PS button worked for me. I held it 11 seconds, and the controller turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do a wireless sync via Bluetooth with your computer to be able to turn off the controller easily. But then you'd have to resync your controller with the playstation when you want to use it on ps3 again. Best to have a least two controllers, so you wouldn't have to switch them over as often. Only when playing co-op.

But for that you need a Bluetooth dongle and proper drivers.