# How can I stop getting BSoDs when using MotionInJoy?

Tags: pc, controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I've been using MotionInJoy for quite a while in order to use my PS3's controller as a gamepad, but have never been able to overcome a very serious issue I'm having with this setup.

I never shut my computer down, as I prefer to have it hibernate (I'm on Win7 64-bit, by the way). However, whenever I hibernate my machine with my PS3 controller plugged in after having used it as a gamepad, I am **always** greeted by a blue screen of death when turning my machine back on. The only way I've found to avoid this so far is to [safely turn off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46856/when-using-my-ps3-controller-as-a-gamepad-how-can-i-turn-it-off-properly) the controller and then physically disconnect it from my computer before hibernating.

There are two main disadvantages to "solving" the problem this way:

1. It's a hassle.
2. It's something you can forget to do.

I'm looking for a proper solution, where this issue would be resolved permanently without the requirement of constant fidgeting. I've tried snooping around online but all I could find were some confirmations of the problem back from the end of 2010, so I'm wide open for suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the driver - someone might have a workaround, but the only people who can truly *fix* the problem are the people who wrote the MotionInJoy drivers.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the memory dump?

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I haven't kept one around, and I'm not overly keen on BSoDing my machine just to get one.

Comment: Does this happen when you Sleep the computer instead of Hibernate?  Hibernate is flaky and unreliable in my experience.

Comment: @Amarok Hibernate has always served me loyally. Also, my computer immediately turns back on if I tell it to go to sleep. The wonders of PCs.

Comment: Which type of blue screen did you get?  The Windows event viewer should be able to tell you a bugcheck error code.  This may be be a hexadecimal number consisting of numbers and letters.  Maybe check the event viewer's system log.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution to this problem, honestly, is to switch from the MotionInJoy drivers to something else. I use [SCPToolkit](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-ScpToolkit-XInput-Wrapper-aka-ScpServer-Reloaded) with my PS3 controller and since I switched from MotionInJoy I haven't had any problems with crashing or BSOD at all.

I know it's not exactly the answer you're looking for, but hopefully that helps. :/